# How to Split the String into sub string in java

Tags: java, substr

I am getting this data from my local server.

```
Bundle[{json={"productId":"4","unseenIds":[1,4,8]",
   "id":"8","message":"You have a new request for your product"}, 
   collapse_key=do_not_collapse}]
```

I have to split this data into:

```
{"productId":"4","unseenIds":"[1,4,8]",
   "id":"8","message":"You have a new request for your product"}
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: Inside bundle as an array?

Comment: Its totally a string

Comment: You mean, Bundle[{json={"productId":"4","unseenIds":"[1,4,8]","id":"8","message":"You have a new request for your product"}, collapse_key=do_not_collapse}] is totally string.

Comment: String json = yourString.substring(13);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split with `=` and remove extra things, This would be a dirty solution, since your String is not properly formatted, I am not finding anything good.

suppose `str` is your string,

```
  String tokens[] =  str.split("=");
  String result = tokens[1].replace(", collapse_key","");
```

or

```
  String result = tokens[1].substring(0, (tokens[1].length()  -15));
```

Another solution would be like this,

```
   result = str.substring(<index of first = >, str.length() - <length of unwanted string at the end> );
```

ie,

```
 //re-check indexes  
 result = str.substring(13, str.length()-35);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String json = yourString.substring(13, yourString.length() - 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
please read :
dont parse the string !!!!
it should be automatically 

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/


<dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>


    import java.util.List;

    public class User {

        private String name;
        private int age;
        private List<String> messages;

        //getters and setters
    }

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
    import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
    import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

    public class JacksonExample {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

            try {

                // Convert JSON string from file to Object
                User user = mapper.readValue(new File("G:\\user.json"), User.class);
                System.out.println(user);

                // Convert JSON string to Object
                String jsonInString = "{\"age\":33,\"messages\":[\"msg 1\",\"msg 2\"],\"name\":\"mkyong\"}";
                User user1 = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, User.class);
                System.out.println(user1);

            } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
```